# WebView crashes on navigation popBackStack() with Jetpack Compose LazyColumn

Tags: android-webview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have WebView inside the LazyColumn. It shows up fine. The thing is when I try to navigate back by calling navController.popBackStack(), I got fatal crash (Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)).

I ran it on the emulator. It works fine when click the "Back" button in the emulator.

Also, it works fine when I replace LazyColumn with Column.

Any idea or thought?

Comment: I am facing this issue in Column also. getting the same fatal crash and the logs just print (Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)). Did you find any solution

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and you can fix this in some ways that I've found:

- destroying your WebViev `webView.destroy()` or making it invisible `webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` when your screen disappears.
- adding alpha = 0.99F (any value but less than 1) to WebView.  `webView.alpha = 0.99F`

Comment: I did webView.destroy() in fragment onDetach event. It works fine. However, I'm looking for the solution for the code written in Jetpack Compose way. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Setting `webView.destroy()` in `DisposableEffect` didn't work for us. On the other hand setting `webView.alpha = 0.99f` in `AndroidView` `factory` works like a charm. We found that it depends on installed chromium version. They fixed it once https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=944020#c11 but it's start to occurred when we upgrade `androidx.compose.ui:ui` from `1.3.0-alpha01` to `1.3.0-alpha02`.

Comment: I couldn't get the webView.destroy() working either, but webView.alpha = 0.99f works. Ridiculous, but I try not to care. Thank you.

Comment: @wrozwad your answer is correct. It works. They didn't fix it in androidx.compose.ui:ui-*:1.6.0-beta01 but your solution works.

Comment: in my case, I didn't need the `verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` in the parent `Column` which `WebView` exist as a child which is works without it alhamdulilah

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the crash `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) WebView` happened if `.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()`, was added to the column as a parent of WebView. (This was required to enable scroll-up when the WebView is launched in the bottom sheet)

The alpha approach didn't work for me.
I solved it by replacing the WebView with an empty View as follows:

First, define destroyWebView: Boolean outside of the Column

```
var destroyWebView by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

Add another state in the Column using rememberUpdatedState, and then replace the WebView with an empty View:

```
val webViewDestroyed = rememberUpdatedState(destroyWebView)

                if (webViewDestroyed.value) {
                    AndroidView(factory = {
                        View(it)
                    })
                } else {
                    AndroidView(factory = {
                        WebView(it).apply {
                            ...
                        }
                    }, update = {
                        it.loadUrl(url)
                    })
```

Comment: removing the `.verticalScroll` works for my case alhamdulillah

Answer (score 0):

When using `WebView` inside `LazyColumn` try using the `remember` function to retain the state across rebuilds. Alternatively, you can try a different layout component like `VerticalScroller` to wrap the `WebView`.

```kotlin
LazyColumn{
    items(items){
    // ...
        remember {
            WebView(/* ... */)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I got below error when trying to wrap WebView inside remember.

*Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun <T> remember(crossinline calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)*

Comment: BTW, I have already used rememberWebViewState to remember the state across compositions.